# Cassandra read timeout because of some response size limit reached?

Tags: cassandra

I encountered a strange behavior on cassandra 3.0:

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  id text,
  ts text,
  score decimal,
  type text,
  values text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC)
```

and the following query (which returns instantly):

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace.table WHERE id='someId' AND ts IN ('2017-10-15','2017-10-16','2017-10-17','2017-10-18','2017-10-19','2017-10-20','2017-10-21','2017-10-22','2017-10-23','2017-10-24','2017-10-25','2017-10-26','2017-10-27','2017-10-28','2017-10-29','2017-10-30','2017-10-31','2017-11-01','2017-11-02','2017-11-03','2017-11-04','2017-11-05','2017-11-06');
```

**If I add another day in the IN clause, the response never comes (even after 10 minutes!!!):**

SELECT * FROM keyspace.table WHERE id='someId' AND ts IN ('2017-10-15','2017-10-16','2017-10-17','2017-10-18','2017-10-19','2017-10-20','2017-10-21','2017-10-22','2017-10-23','2017-10-24','2017-10-25','2017-10-26','2017-10-27','2017-10-28','2017-10-29','2017-10-30','2017-10-31','2017-11-01','2017-11-02','2017-11-03','2017-11-04','2017-11-05','2017-11-06', ***'2017-11-07'***);

**The 'values' column may have large json data. There is some flag in cassandra.yaml with some size threshold or something like this?** I guess adding another day in the query reaches some limit somewhere...in cassandra system.log I didn't see anything relevant to this.

Comment: What happens if you have the same SELECT query with just date? Do you experience any slowdown?

Comment: @Aki no, it returns instantly

Comment: Are you running your query via cqlsh? If not, give it a try. Just before running it, call "TRACING ON". This might hold a clue where your slowness is coming from...

Comment: @Aki the test is via cqlsh...tracing ON does not display if I get timeout. Only on valid response it is displayed I think

Comment: @Aki - also I noticed if I let that date in the query and I delete another one, the query works instantly....it seems reaching a specific number of params triggers the timeout...I'm almost sure it has to do with some response size limit somewhere

Comment: how many rows are you looking at here?  Is it a small number?  If so this is likely a limit, if not its likely a data size problem on the coordinator.

Comment: @Highstead - I'm looking at 23 rows. If I look at 24 rows, I get timeout(the size of each row is almost identical). All these 23/24 rows are on the same machine (same partition key -> 'someId')

Comment: `nodetool cfhistograms <keyspace> <table>`  What is your partition size distribution?  Additionally how large are these rows (MB?)

Comment: @Highstead 50% ->1331             
75% -> 3973            
95% ->219342
98% ->654949
99% ->1358102

Comment: @Highstead - I noticed querying from CQLSH on another node it works, no timeout even for more rows. I noticed in this node, there is no read latency when I run the cfhistrograms. When I run cfhistrograms on the node which cause timeout I get around 30000 microseconds read latency

Comment: So if it succeeds on another node (with the same id) and is succeeds on this node when you drop 1 of the 'in' clauses i would guess its a memory pressure issue that is triggering MANY GCs from which this node is not recovering.

Comment: The node that exhibits slow behavior, is there a compaction running? You can check with nodetool compactionstats command. From the other node, you could be working with a healthy replica that does not have other memory-consuming things going on.

Comment: @Aki - I ran multiple times that command and always there was 0 pending tasks so no compaction was running in that times when I ran the command

Comment: @Aki - I watch with jmx the Java memory on the node and it is around 4GM of 8GB total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it succeeds on one node and not another while the query will work with 1 less 'in' clause I would guess this is a memory pressure issue.  To eliminate the 'query parsing problem' you can re-write your query as:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 'x' AND ts >= '2017-10-15' AND ts <= '2017-11-07';`

The in clause is only truly useful if you start bucketing your data.  This is a good approach if you have hotspots or if you see 1 node with much higher load than the others.

To bucket your data you would want to do something like:

`CREATE TABLE table (
  id text,
  ts text,
  score decimal,
  type text,
  values text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id, ts), type)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (type DESC)`

Your data would now be partitioned by id AND day.  Your query would then become what you have now:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='x' AND ts in ('2017-01-01')`

This will better distribute data on the HDDs and allow better parallelization from cassandra.  This **WILL NOT** fix the memory pressure issue.  To fix that you would want to move the aggregation of data from the coordinator to your application layer.

This means running N `SELECT ... WHERE id='x' and ts = '2017-01-01';` queries.

Comment: definetly looks like a mem. issue and the data does not seem to be distributed evenly on the cluster. I will change the table scheme as per your suggestion :)

Comment: One advantage of your previous schema is that multiple "ts" info for the '"id" was on the same node, which will make lookup faster. Again, but it looks like it was creating memory pressure as @Highstead identified. New schema will better distribute data across different nodes, but when doing an IN query now you are querying multiple nodes which will add additional latency to your SELECT query.

Comment: Aki is correct.  You will suffer some latency associated with the additional network hops.  This could be mostly mitigated by running the queries in parallel at the application level.