# Info about some cassandra TRACE log

Tags: cassandra

[image]

I managed to trace a read timeout (client timeout initially) by looking into **system_traces.sessions and system_traces.events.**

The trace shows a duration of 10 minutes for the query (of course, the client driver sent timeout after 1 min I think). The huge duration was spot in one row from the trace string (last one - look into the attached image)

Can anyone have a clue about that timeout? It looks like a bug to me. 
In order to get this timeout I only need to add another parameter in some IN clause (24 params in the IN). If the query contains only 23 params in IN query everything works like charm (response arrives within 1-2 seconds)

Another interesting thing is that I see this in debug.log(/var/log/cassandra) at the time I get timeout in trace

**DEBUG [Thrift:2608] 2017-11-15 13:48:05,611 ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 0 of 1 responses**

This question is somehow related to this: [Cassandra read timeout because of some response size limit reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291069/cassandra-read-timeout-because-of-some-response-size-limit-reached)

Comment: Maybe you could share the table structure and the query? and maybe some sample data

Comment: @Horia - the problem is manifesting on more tables (I migrated some tables from an old cluster with cassa 2.0). I've edited the question and I added some info I found in cassa's debug.log file.

Comment: I was thinking that adding some new data to the query might trigger a full cluster scan

Comment: @Horia - the data is added frequently ....I also tried nodetool repair...

Comment: @AlexandruCircus I think you'll find more luck with this issue on the Cassandra user list. http://cassandra.apache.org/community/#mailing

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson - I already sent an email to them. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I just realized that when I saw your image posted there. Don't forget to answer your own question if you get a solution.

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson Yes of course :)

Comment: One thing that you could do is to monitor the nodes in the cluster using jconsole. I would monitor the garbage collector to see how it works. Did you also check gc.log?

Comment: What I would also do/monitor: enable trace for GCInspector, check coordinator latency (IN clauses can trigger checking more nodes than necessary), local latency per table (this one can increase if you have gc issues, lots of sstables, not enough cache), check native transport requests, is disk filling up, a lot of tombstones, uneven data distribution.